# Screenscrolling in vim

Tags: vim

is it possible to make vim scroll by screenlines instead of file lines?

More precisely: i edit texts with large paragraphs, and i put enter only at the end of a paragraph. Thus, for vim, each of my paragraphs is a single line, and these lines are very long. When moving around vim jumps very long distances and i get lost. Vim seems to be suitable only for editing programs?

I know about mapping j to gj and so on (i have done them). However just mapping these is not enough i also want the scrolling to be corrected for screenlines.

I have done some searching , but i cannot find a clear answer to whether screen line scrolling is possible or not.

If it is not possible, would somebody know of an, possibly ugly hack to do it? In its current setting vim is not usable, which is sad because i prefer its other features very much over the other editors around. (i do not like the idea of having to learn emacs ...)

Comment: When googling around I found one trick which slightly improves behaviour of vim (but it is def not a solution): you can set the var scrolloff to a very big number; then vim tries to keep your cursor vertically centered. But it still jumps bec vim centers wrt to physical lines (not wrt screenlines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, the answer is: no.

Browse through this [somewhat] recent nabble thread where Bram Moolenaar himself describes why this hasn't been implemented yet. (basically, it has too much potential for introducing bugs)

http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Scrolling-screen-lines-I-knew-it-s-impossible-td3358342.html